# it is not able to retrieve correct value from variable in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysqli

below I hava query where it performs a query to find all of the Course Details from the database and display it in a drop down menu and then the course which is selected is display in a message using the `$outputcourse` variable:

```
    $sql = "SELECT CourseId, CourseNo, CourseName FROM Course ORDER BY CourseNo"; 

    $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

    $sqlstmt->execute(); 

    $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseNo, $dbCourseName);

    $courses = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

    $courseHTML = "";  
    $courseHTML .= '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
    $courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

    $outputcourse = ""; 
    $hiddencourse = ""; 

    while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
    { 
    $course = $dbCourseId;
    $courseno = $dbCourseNo;
    $coursename = $dbCourseName; 
    $courseHTML .= "<option value='".$course."'>" . $courseno . " - " . $coursename . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  

    if (isset($_POST['courses']) && ($_POST['courses'] == $course)) {
    $outputcourse .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseno .  " - "  . $coursename . "</p>";
    $hiddencourse .= "<p><input type='hidden' id='hiddencourse' value='". $courseno . " - " . $coursename ."'></p>";
}

    } 

    $courseHTML .= '</select>';
```

Now what I want to do is display the modules which does not belong in the course selected. Now my query works fine in php but the problem I am having is that if I use mysqli to run this query, it is unable to retireve the `$dbCourseId` variable in the where clause so the WHERE clause is incorrect.

The WHERE clause was suppose to display the courseId which was suppose to be `1` but it keeps displaying `10`. If I choose a different course where the courseId should be `3`, it still outputs `10`.

So what my question is that which variable should go in the bind->param() in the code below and how can I retireve the correct courseId of the selected course?

Below is the code for the query:

```
$modulequery = "
SELECT
m.ModuleId, m.ModuleNo, m.ModuleName, m.Credits
FROM
Module m
WHERE
m.ModuleId NOT IN (
SELECT cm.ModuleId
FROM Course_Module cm
WHERE cm.CourseId = ?
)
ORDER BY m.ModuleNo
";

$moduleqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($modulequery);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$moduleqrystmt->bind_param("i",$dbCourseId);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$moduleqrystmt->execute(); 

$moduleqrystmt->bind_result($dbModuleId,$dbModuleNo,$dbModuleName,$dbCredits);

$moduleqrystmt->store_result();

$modulenum = $moduleqrystmt->num_rows();     

echo $dbCourseId;
```

Comment: where is this `$dbCourseId` variable is initialised and assigned a value. I only see it's only assigned to some other value.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar What I am trying to do is use the $dbCourseId from the Query where it selects the course and use it to then act as a parameter to use in the module query. Am I using the wrong variable then?

Comment: `onchange="getModules();"` when calling this call pass the selected option id.

Comment: @Y Ignore the onchange="getModules();" I copied and pasted the drop down menu code ut forgot to remove that as I do not need that line in this code

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I have figured out the problem and posted the answer. Thanks anyway for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Below the if statement where you check if the user has clicked on the `courseSubmit` button include the line as below:

```
if (isset($_POST['courseSubmit'])) {    

        //get the form data 
    $coursesdrop = (isset($_POST['courses'])) ? $_POST['courses'] : '';
```

Now as you have each Course option contain a value of `$dbCourseId`, you can use `$coursesdrop` variable in order to retireve the Course ID in the other queries.

So in the other query change:

`$moduleqrystmt->bind_param("i",$dbCourseId);`

To:

`$moduleqrystmt->bind_param("i",$coursesdrop);`

That fixes the problem